# How many collections(classes) can I have in 1 Application on Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com for my iOS application.

How many collections(classes) can I have in 1 Application on Parse.com?

Is there any limit for creating collections(classes)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the number of classes you can create. The data browser will only show up to 100, but all the classes are available via the API.

Verified by Parse.com here: https://www.parse.com/questions/classes-limit